# How to set width of JQuery UI checkboxradio

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

my site often has `JQuery` **UI checkbox** radio items arranged one on top of the other.  It seems that the width of the radio item is determined by the number of characters in the label of the item.  I would like to set the widths of these items so that they are the same and look better when placed on top of each other.

Is this possible to do using `JQuery` UI or `javascript`?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to add/edit the css rule for the ui-checkboxradio-label class

Comment: That worked a treat!  Do I use the same class if i want to align the label text to the left?  I tried placing 'text-align: left;' into that same rule but it did not work.  Thanks again.

Comment: you'll need to play around with the ui-checkboxradio-icon class, probably make the icon float right, since the label created has a couple of spans and the text